How to find missing combination of 3 columns in Pandas given all possible values for each column
column A and column C can take values [s1,s2...sn]. column B can take values [a1,a2...am]. So basically we should have n * m * n rows in the pandas df. 
Expected: 
A   B   C
s1  a1  s1
s1  a1  s2
.
s1  a1  sn
.
s1  an  sn
.
.
sn  an  sn

How do I efficiently identify which rows/combinations are missing and append it to my pandas data frame?
I could create all combinations and do a difference but that seems inefficient for large data sets.

use Finding all possible combinations and compare two lists in python, no need to do that more efficiently because the is not a more efficient way which will save you time.

Some kind of binary-ish search after sorting the rows, where you compare what is at a location with what should be there (so you can tell how many are missing before and after that row)?

If you need all possible rows, why don't you just create an empty table with all possible rows, and load the data into that, instead of just loading in the potentially defective table?  I assume there are other columns here; otherwise, the exercise is pointless.

Yes there are other columns in the dataframe. I need to identify and add missing rows and set a default value of 0 to remaining columns

import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2'], 
        'B': ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a1'], 
        'C': ['s1', 's2', 's5', 's1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

A_values = df['A'].unique()
B_values = df['B'].unique()
C_values = df['C'].unique()

# Create a mapping of existing combinations for each (A, B) pair
existing_combinations = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    a, b, c = row['A'], row['B'], row['C']
    if (a, b) not in existing_combinations:
        existing_combinations[(a, b)] = set()
    existing_combinations[(a, b)].add(c)

# Identify missing combinations
missing_rows = []
for a in A_values:
    for b in B_values:
        valid_C_values = C_values  
        existing_C_values = existing_combinations.get((a, b), set())  
        
        missing_C_values = set(valid_C_values) - existing_C_values
 
        for c in missing_C_values:
            missing_rows.append((a, b, c))


missing_df = pd.DataFrame(missing_rows, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df_updated = pd.concat([df, missing_df], ignore_index=True)
print(df_updated)

Output
     A   B   C
0   s1  a1  s1
1   s1  a1  s2
2   s1  a2  s5
3   s2  a1  s1
4   s1  a1  s5
5   s1  a2  s1
6   s1  a2  s2
7   s2  a1  s2
8   s2  a1  s5
9   s2  a2  s1
10  s2  a2  s2
11  s2  a2  s5

